# How to remove QLayout from other QLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a layout that contain other layout (sublayout). I need to remove sublayout with content from layout. How i can do it?

```
QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout; 
QHBoxLayout* subLayout = new QHBoxLayout; 
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   subLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton(this)); //some content of sublayout
mainLayout->addLayout(subLayout);
setLayout(mainLayout);
```

There are only `QLayout::removeWidget()`, but not something like `QLayout::removeLayout()` in this class. Just 
`delete subLayout` or

```
QLayoutItem *item;
while ((item = subLayout->takeAt(0)))
   delete item;
delete subLayout;
```

have no correct effect too (Content still remains on the screen).

So how?

Comment: `delete subLayout` should have worked if the parent hierarchy is correct, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void QLayout::removeItem(QLayoutItem *item)`

> Removes the layout item item from the layout. It is the caller's
>   responsibility to delete the item.
>
> Notice that item can be a layout (since QLayout inherits QLayoutItem).